# How to Evaluate a Variable Value from a String?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been absolutely tearing my hair out over this.  Is there a simple way to pull a variable value from a string?  I'm trying to use this to cleanly check the value of multiple similar variables.  Example:

```
Dim BoxString As String

For i = 1 To 100
    BoxString = "response = Report" & i & "Box.value"

    Application.Evaluate (BoxString)

    If response = True Then
        '...
    End If

Next i
```

For context, I'm using this to evaluate which boxes on a UserForm were selected, and perform an action for each one that was.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: A userfom has a collection of controls in which controls can be accessed via their name. See: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/controls-collection.html

Comment: `Application` is the Excel host application object... it knows nothing about any VBA variables/expressions. It can evaluate Excel formulas in the context of the active workbook, but not VBA code. `theFormInstance.Controls(controlName).Value` will probably give you what you want.

Comment: Controls() is exactly what I'm looking for!  Thanks a million times for the quick responses John Coleman and Mathieu Guindon!